# Communal commandment sources?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, tzibur-community

What are some good (preferably authoritative) sources that explain the concept and legal ramifications of *mitzvos tziboriyos* - obligations that fall upon the public as opposed to the individual?

I am thinking specifically of the commandment to build the Temple, but general information or information specific to other mitzvos would be great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm.  R' Yosef Rosen Rogatchover spends some time philosophically addressing "what is a tzibur" as a whole vs. the sum of its parts.  More on that here:  http://media.libsyn.com/media/kmtt/sheelot_teshuvot_eng_10_5770_BTabory.mp3

Whether weekly Torah reading is an individual or communal obligation is well-hashed out in the Acharonim.   Afraid I don't have specific references off-hand for that one.  I'd say start with later Halacha seforim and work backwards.

As for building the Temple -- you can always try responsa Binyan Tzion (get the name?) #1.  Does the Aruch HaShulchan HaAtid deal with it?  Probably does.

Wish I had more helpful or solid references.  Good luck!